# Rails admin display :thumb image

Tags: ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-4, thumbnails, rails-admin

I have the following code:

`config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
list do
      field :id        #currentId set in app/views/rails_admin/main/index
      field :year
      field :title
      field :intro
      field :description
      field :confidential
      field :star
      field :image do
        formatted_value do
          bindings[:view].tag(:img, { :src => bindings[:object].image.url(:thumb)}) 
        end
      end
    end
```

`app/models/submission.rb`

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Image attachment and validations
  has_attached_file :file,
    :url => "/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :styles => { :thumb => "100x100#", :small  => "150x150>", :medium => "200x200" }

  # Validate attachment type
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => 'application/pdf'

end
```

Question: On the list view, why don't I get that `:thumb` image and I get a very very large image? I guess the chopping procedure is not working at all?

Comment: Have you created new submission after adding this style configration??

Comment: Yes, I just added a new project and the image is still displayed like very large!

Comment: :content_type => 'application/pdf' Why it is validating for PDF??

Comment: You're right. I was resizing the wrong model! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great np mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is

```
validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => 'application/pdf'
```

and you are expecting images to be resized I think you check your modal and implementation again

Follow this

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Comment: I moved the sizing to the right model, but I am still getting the huge image on the index page

Comment: Please create new projects

Comment: Or do  Project.find_each { |u| u.file.reprocess! } For to create thumbnails of existing files

Comment: I did recreate a new project, and the thumb is still not there. The image on the page is definitely not 100x100

Comment: Can you see the processing of paperclip in the console or you can check the public folder for images or if still don't understand paste the modal code and also be sure that your form is accepting the image parameters

Comment: I just checked the public folder and the paperclip is definitely not resizing the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128836/discussion-between-wish-zone-and-vlad-balanescu).